# jQuery magnefic popup save form data without full submit

Tags: jquery, json, forms, perl

I am working on a form that has multiple form fields and at the end an image upload form inside a jquery magnific popup. (Rough mockup below:)

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/upl-img.cgi",
    data: {
      "dir":$("#filetype").val(),
      "cmd":"Upload",
      "upload":$("#upload").val
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <!-- stuff stuff stuff -->
  <input type="textfield" id="name" name="name"></input>
  <input type="textfield" id="height" name="height"></input>
  <!-- etc. etc... -->
<button type="upload" id="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">Submit</button>
<button type="reset">Reset</button>
 </form>

<form id="form2">
  <!-- stuff stuff stuff -->
  <input type="textfield" id="age" name="age"></input>
  <input type="textfield" id="birthday" name="birthday"></input>
  <!-- etc. etc... -->
<button type="upload" id="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">Submit</button>
<button type="reset">Reset</button>
 </form>

<form id="form3" class="magnificPopup">
  <input type="textfield" id="filename" name="filename"></input>
  <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload"></input>
  <select id="filetype" name="filetype">
      <option value="path/to/">Location 1</option>
                  ....etc
  </select>

<button type="upload" id="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">Submit</button>
<button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

the upl-img.cgi file contains the functions that upload the files to the database. Right now what is happening is that when the "submit" button is pressed, it posts the images in the defined directory by doing a full form submission...I want form3 to post the data without doing a full form submission, if that makes sense...I'm not sure how well I am describing what I need

Answer (score 0):

You must cancel the default event, otherwise the form still gets submitted.

```
('#submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({

    });
});
```

Also I see that you are using the same "id" for multiple elements - "id" should (must) be document-wide unique.

Comment: Oh the multiple same id's were just copy/pasted, just there for filler in this skeleton code example, I guess I was too lazy to fill multiple ones...but yeah in the document itself all id's are unique

Comment: But just to confirm, doing it this way, will it POST the data to the server without doing a full form submit?

Comment: Normally (without javascript) clicking on a submit button will submit the containing form - that's why there is `event.preventDefault()` to cancel this default behavior. Instead the $.ajax is called which sends the request with ajax.